# padding-left depends of the subnav deep

Tags: css, navigation, padding

I have a vertical navigation with sub categories having subcategories and so on.

Elements of the first group need a padding of 20px, of the second one 40px and so on. The result should be something like this:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="list-group">
  <a class="list-group-item" href="#">Test 0</a>
  <div class="list-group">
    <a class="list-group-item" href="#" style="padding-left: 40px;">Test 1</a>
    <a class="list-group-item" href="#" style="padding-left: 40px;">Test 1</a>
    <div class="list-group">
      <a class="list-group-item" href="#" style="padding-left: 60px;">Test 2</a>
      <div class="list-group">
        <a class="list-group-item" href="#" style="padding-left: 80px;">Test 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I want to solve it with a CSS rule, without Javascript and not write it into the html element.
The deep of the navigation can be n elements and I don't want to implement n rules like this:

```
.list-group .list-group-item {}
.list-group .list-group .list-group-item {}
.list-group .list-group .list-group .list-group-item {}
```

So is it possible to solve this problem with just some CSS rules?

Answer (score -1):

I would use `ul` and `li` tags for something like this as it's easier to understand and track. Here is something I came up with, that did what you asked without javascript:

```
HTML
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Item1</a>
        <ul>
            <li>Hello</li>
            <li><a href="#"></a>Hello
                <ul>
                    <li>Bye</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
</ul>

CSS
ul {
    padding: 0;
}

ul li {
    list-style: none;
}
ul > li {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Let me know if that solved it for you!

Comment: The hover effect for link has no 100% width as in my example so it's not the solution i am locking for.

Comment: @mimo Oh I was just showing how you can do it with `ul` and `li`. Updating it now.